# Check If only numeric values were entered in input. (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if users enter correct phone number in, with help of jQuery, so far I got to this stage:

```
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
if (phone !== "") {
    //Check if phone is numeric
    $("label#phone_error").show(); //Show error
    $("input#phone").focus(); //Focus on field
    return false;
}
```

Basically it checks if phone number was entered and if it was, I would like to check if it is a numeric value and if it is not display the error messages.
Could anyone help with checking if it is numeric?

Comment: Take into consideration that phone numbers actually is not a number, but a string containing numbers. 

Users are going to write the numbers in weird ways, and if you have a global application, even weirder. Remember country codes starts with 00 or +, the + is valid as a phone number, but not a valid number.

Sorry if i´m off subject here but i´ve spent too much time filling in "not a valid number" on websites

Comment: You could also go as far as to remove characters that are not numbers and then construct the input as you wish using a switch statement that uses jquery `.val()` and `.length()` `var valLength = $(this).val().length;` in your conditionals. `switch(valLength) {` then add cases at your length values that check for numeric values or use a regex conditional if statement to identify if your value is numeric at that `case:` value in your length array.

Comment: Why/why isn't regexp is better than JQuery isNumeric() ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use jQuery method to check whether a value is numeric or other type.

```
$.isNumeric()
```

Example

```
$.isNumeric("46")
```

true

```
$.isNumeric(46)
```

true

```
$.isNumeric("dfd")
```

false

Answer (score 64):

Try this ... it will make sure that the string "phone" only contains digits and will at least contain one digit

```
if(phone.match(/^\d+$/)) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: This is a good option since jQuery.isNumeric() does not validate long values (Int64).

Comment: I think it important to mention that with regards to the OPs original question in how to make sure a phone number only has numeric values weeds out (Int64) values. A phone number form input will have tops 30 inputs. For a US phone input, a likely ridiculously long entry may equal... (555) 555-5555 ext:(5555). So we have a total of 25 character placements being used in our example string. A reg ex with restriction of 25 placements  is all we need to ensure (int64) is not used by someone who is using the form improperly. Just sayin...

Answer (score 28):

There is a built-in function in jQuery to check this (isNumeric), so try the following:

```
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
    if (phone !== "" && !$.isNumeric(phone)) {
  //Check if phone is numeric
  $("label#phone_error").show(); //Show error
  $("input#phone").focus(); //Focus on field
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize this had been added to jQuery.  Should that be `$.isNumeric`?

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work if you have long values (Int64), so that would only work for normal int values.

Comment: $.isNumeric() does not work for + and - signs before the number, and also ignores the decimal points.

Answer (score 4):

I used this to check if all the text boxes had numeric values:

```
if(!$.isNumeric($('input:text').val())) {
        alert("All the text boxes must have numeric values!");
        return false;
    }
```

or for one:

```
$.isNumeric($("txtBox").val());
```

Available with jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS

Check that out.  It should be just what you're looking for.  A US phone validation plugin for jQuery.

If you want to do it on your own, you're going to be in for a good amount of work.  Check out the `isNaN()` function.  It tells you if it is not a number.  You're also going to want to brush up on your regular expressions for validation.  If you're using RegEx, you can go without `isNaN()`, as you'll be testing for that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I used this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (!(/^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/.test(document.getElementById('txtRemittanceNumber').value))){
            alert('Please enter only numbers into amount textbox.')
            }
            else
            {
            alert('Right Number');
            }
```

I hope this code may help you.

in this code if condition will return true if there is any legal decimal number of any number of decimal places. and  alert will come up with the message "Right Number" other wise it will show a alert popup with message "Please enter only numbers into amount textbox.".

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

for future visitors, you can add this functon that allow user to enter only numbers: you will only have to add jquery and the class name to the input check that into  http://jsfiddle.net/celia/dvnL9has/2/

```
$('.phone_number').keypress(function(event){
var numero= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
 var myArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
index = myArray.indexOf(numero);// 1
var longeur= $('.phone_number').val().length;
if(window.getSelection){
 text = window.getSelection().toString();
 } if(index>=0&text.length>0){
  }else if(index>=0&longeur<10){
    }else {return false;} });
```

Comment: Not working in Firefox Quantum 59.0.2, however use keydown instead

Comment: Worth noting as well that with keydown literally no other keystrokes work. Even delete/backspace doesn't work, which might cause some UX issues.

Answer (score 1):

I used this kind of validation .... checks the pasted text and if it contains alphabets, shows an error for user and then clear out the box after delay for the user to check the text and make appropriate changes.

```
$('#txtbox').on('paste', function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            setTimeout(function (e) {
                if (($this.val()).match(/[^0-9]/g))
                {
                    $("#errormsg").html("Only Numerical Characters allowed").show().delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");                       
                    setTimeout(function (e) {
                        $this.val(null);
                    },2500);
                }                   
            }, 5);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer to the question, but one other option for phone validation, is to ensure the number gets entered in the format you are expecting.

Here is a function I have worked on that when set to the `onInput` event, will strip any non-numerical inputs, and auto-insert dashes at the "right" spot, assuming xxx-xxx-xxxx is the desired output.

`<input oninput="formatPhone()">`

```
function formatPhone(e) {
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
    e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '-' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
}
```