# How to check contents of input in "real time"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a web form and it's been set up with a text field to receive what is expected to be a numeric value. The form won't submit if the contents of this field aren't numeric but there was no error message put in place to let the user know that they filled this field out wrong.

My question is...is there a way in real time to check what's in the input and do something to tell the user they aren't filling it out properly? If everything is ok I want the border of the input to be green, if not then make the border red and change the default text of the input to tell them we only want numbers.

This is loosely what I've got so far as my starting point...

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="btn-blue" id="testing"></input>
```

JS:

```
$('#testing').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Amount');
var useramount = $("#testing").val();
if (useramount.match(/^\d+$/)) {
   $("#testing").css({border: "2px solid #33CC00 !important"});
} 
else {
  $("#testing").css({border: "2px solid #FF0000 !important"});
  $("#testing").innerHTML = "";
  $('#testing').attr('placeholder', 'Only Numbers Please');
}
```

I've borrowed the basic principle of the validation from this previously asked question:
[Check If only numeric values were entered in input. (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086174/check-if-only-numeric-values-were-entered-in-input-jquery)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it is unrelated to your question - but have you considered using `type="number"`?

Comment: Yes - unfortunately the form is already built and was done by another developer and the portion of the CMS that generates forms doesn't allow you to specify what type of input you want. It just spits out a generic input field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event to get changes when the user is typing inside of the field. On the change event you will be given the element corresponding to the input element the event listener is attached to as [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Using this reference you are able to get the value of the input by using the `value` property on the element.

After you have retrieved the value you will need to verify that it is in fact numerical. Thankfully jQuery provides a method called [isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) that allows us to do just that.

Once we've established the fact that the value is indeed numerical you can either apply a class or just set the style to what you want to be. Make sure you also check if the value has been emptied so the user does not get confused.

As for the validation message - it's not a good idea to set the value of the input as the user is interacting with said element. Instead I've chosen to add textual element to represent the message that will be shown conditionally based on the validation state.

```js
// Add error message element after input.
$('#some-number').after('<span class="error-message">Please enter numbers only!</span>')

$('#some-number').on('input', function (evt) {
  var value = evt.target.value
  
  if (value.length === 0) {
    evt.target.className = ''
    return
  }

  if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
    evt.target.className = 'valid'
  } else {
    evt.target.className = 'invalid'
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input.invalid + .error-message {
  display: initial;
}

.error-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="some-number">
```

Comment: This one works perfectly and the only reason I'm not marking it as the accepted answer is because it takes me additional work to insert the error-message via function into the HTML markup. Otherwise it worked perfectly and I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 You can easily add that element with jQuery - let me update my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated - I've been trying to get that in there myself but couldn't quite figure it out, if you can that'd be great and I'd have this as the chosen answer as it's cleaner than what I originally was doing

Comment: Got this up and running right now and all is working well, I ended up using the error message from DefaultError's answer in tandem with your over arching function and it's all working perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the [`onkeypress` Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp). Every time the user presses a key while the input box is selected, update the input's value.

Example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input-box");
var inputValue = document.getElementById("input-box").value;

input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  inputValue = document.getElementById("input-box").value;
  // do something with it
});
```

```html
<input id="input-box"/>
```

I hope I didn't get anything wrong.

Comment: thanks for this - so just so I make sure I follow your logic with this one...It's listening in on whenever a keystroke is recorded inside of the input box? How do i determine what type of value was entered into the input box?

Comment: Yes, it's recording whenever a keystroke is done inside of the input box. Whenever a keystroke happens, it updates the `inputValue` with the current value of the input. As to how you can determine what type of value was entered, I honestly have no idea. However, if you're expecting numbers to come as a value, use `parseInt(inputValue)` or `parseFloat(inputValue)`.

Comment: Thanks for help, it answers how to get the "real time" going but it still doesnt get me all the way there - really appreciate the attempt though!

Answer (score 2):

You could bind your validation logic to a keypress event like

```
$('#target').keydown(function () {
    // validation
});
```

or

```
$("#target").blur(function() {
    // validation
});
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/smzob72e/

Comment: So in this case would the existing if/else I had of testing whether or not it's numerical work just plugged directly into your first example you gave me?

Comment: Yes, you can plug your validation directly into the keydown function and you can access the value with $(this).val();

Comment: Would you be so kind as to put that into a fiddle or a demo, I understand what you're saying conceptually but can't quite figure out the implementation of it - sorry JS isn't my strongest suit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I plugged it into the codepen and it still isn't working though - it seems like in theory it should work but even when i console.log  the initial keydown detection is doesn't seem to be working...maybe an error with CP and not your code...

Comment: I have added a fiddle demo, hope it solves your problem!

Comment: @DefaultError OP asking for a 'realtime' solution - which I assume means as the user is typing.

Comment: yea, but keyup and keydown events are the closest you can get to a realtime validation, isn't it?

Comment: @DefaultError Apologies - I responded to the wrong post. I believe `oninput` is also an event that could be used.

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly - i'll tweak what i've got on my end to make it work. This is the most correct in terms of what my original question was so I'll be marking this one as the accepted answer, thanks a lot for all your help !

Comment: I ended up using the bulk of Jon's answer in the end - although I used snippets of your's as well. Wish there was a way for me to give you both credit with the correct answer. Thanks a bunch for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

Example for me using the vanilla javascript.
I write this to disable the Submit button whenever no text value

```
let textInput = document.getElementById('dataInput') // take the element value
  textInput.addEventListener('input', (test) => { //whenever event input happend
  console.log("text", textInput.value)
    if (textInput.value.length !== 0) {
      document.getElementById('btnSubmit').classList.remove('disabled')
//remove the class disabled in submit button
    } else {
      document.getElementById('btnSubmit').classList.add('disabled')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a Jquery on("input") like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testing')
    .attr('placeholder', 'Enter Amount')
    .on("input", function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var useramount = $this.val();  
        if($.isNumeric(useramount)){
            $this.css("border", "2px solid green !important");
            $this.css("background", "green");
        } else {
            $this.css("border", "2px solid red !important");
            $this.css("background", "red");
            $this.val("");
            $this.attr('placeholder', 'Only Numbers Please');
        }
    });
});
```

The background field is more obviously shown than the border, for educational purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dan - I plugged your function into CodePen and it's not doing anything...any idea? http://codepen.io/hoonin_hooligan/pen/EWeXbP

Comment: Remove your css, just for the test